# confidence value skeleton_tracker

Tags: ros, skeleton-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what does mean the confidence value of skeleton_tracker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194464/confidence-value-skeleton_tracker/) by [idavico](https://answers.ros.org/users/20379/idavico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each joint of the tracked skeleton has a confidence value that represents the goodness/reliability of its position. 1 means good tracking, while 0 bad or no tracking.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [idavico](https://answers.ros.org/users/20379/idavico/) on 2014-10-14**:
but sometimes i get 1 when there is no tracking :s

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-02**:
If there's no tracking you should probably ignore the confidence.